# Chrome Uncaught Syntaxerror: Unexpected end of input

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

The code:

http://pastebin.com/LS1KeQ9t

I don't see anything wrong with it. Why is the Google Chrome console giving me that error at the end of my .js file?

Comment: Works fine for me, problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: Can you put up a page exhibiting the logged error?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome have mechanism for prevent DDoS attack, you can read about it http://dev.chromium.org/throttling

It cause error for me. Try switch it off, type this:

```
chrome://net-internals/#httpThrottling
```